# ¿Cómo se trabaja con el metodo SUPER en Angular?

Tags: angular

Me han pasado un proyecto, y es la primera vez que veo este tipo de estructura de `SUPER` en un archivo services de la carpeta services (**Nota**: todos los archivos services del proyecto tienen esta estructura).

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CrudService} from './FAST-TRACK-FRONTEND/crud.service';
import {HttpGenericService} from './FAST-TRACK-FRONTEND/http-generic.service';
import {UtilsService} from './FAST-TRACK-FRONTEND/utils.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProgramasService extends CrudService<any, any> {
  constructor(
    protected http: HttpGenericService<any>,
    protected utils: UtilsService
  ) {
    super(http, utils, {
      callInSave: true,
      debug: true,
      debounceConfig: 300,
      callInSaveInfinite: false,
      urlDelete: '/programas',
      urlGet: '/programas',
      urlPut: '/programas',
      urlPost: '/programas',
      urlGetInfinite: '',
      messageForSave: 'Programa guardado',
      messageForDelete: 'Programa eliminado',
      messageForUpdate: 'Programa actualizado',
      messageForLoad: 'Realizando operación',
      messageForError: 'Ocurrio un problema realizando esta operación',
      keyLocalStorageList: 'LIST_PROGRAMAS',
      keyLocalStorageSelected: 'PROGRAMA_SELECTED'
    });
    super.get();
  }
}
```

Dentro de la carpeta services hay otra carpeta llamada `Fast-Track-Frontend` pero no contiene nada y por eso el proyecto tiene errores, faltan muchos archivos como `crud`, `utils`, etc. Están importados en los servicios pero no existen en el proyecto.

**Tengo 2 preguntas:**

¿Por qué estos services usan el SUPER?

¿Cómo sería la estructura de esos archivos faltantes?

**Hasta ahora, la forma en la que trabajé los servicios es así:**
Creando metodos los cuales los utilizaba en los componentes que los necesitara.

```js
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Global } from "./global";
import { ParkingModels } from '../models/parking.models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ParkingService {
  public url: string;


  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
  ) {

    this.url = Global.url;

  }

  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- Get Parkings -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  getParkings(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url + '/parkings', { headers: headers });
  }

  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- Guardar Parking -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  saveParking(project: ParkingModels): Observable<any> {
    let params = JSON.stringify(project);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.post(this.url + '/create-parking', params, { headers: headers });
  }

  deleteParking(id: any): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.delete(this.url + '/delete-parking/' + id, { headers: headers });
  }

  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- Guardar Imagen -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  saveIMG(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>, name: string) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let formData: any = new FormData();
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append(name, files[i], files[i].name);
      }

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
          } else {
            reject(xhr.response);
          }
        }
      }

      xhr.open('POST', url, true);
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera pregunta se puede responder. La segunda no, si faltan archivos y el proyecto no funciona por eso es que algo anda mal ahí.

---

¿Por qué se usa `super`?

`super` es una llamada al constructor de la clase padre, que seguramente espera tres parámetros: 2 servicios [http, utils] y un objeto de configuración.

Eso que tienes ahí es un caso de herencia. `CrudService` es una clase padre la cual es extendida por las clases hijas.

Haciendo eso se consigue reutilizar los métodos de `CrudService` y creando diferentes configuraciones según la clase específica que se use.

Abajo se puede ver una estructura de clases simple que sirve como ejemplo:

```
@Injectable()
class CrudService {
  constructor(
    protected http: HttpClient,
    protected utils: unknown,
    protected config: unknown
  ) {}

  method1() {
    console.log(this.config['prop1']);
  }

  method2() {
    console.log(this.config['prop2']);
  }
}

@Injectable()
class ProgramService extends CrudService {
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient, protected utils: unknown) {
    super(http, utils, { prop1: 'hola', prop2: 'adios' });
    super.method1();
    super.method2();
  }
}

@Injectable()
class ProgramService2 extends CrudService {
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient, protected utils: unknown) {
    super(http, utils, { prop1: 'hola1', prop2: 'adios1' });
    super.method1();
    super.method2();
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. ¿Este tema cómo debo buscarlo para profundizar más?

Comment: Para conceptos generales sería: Programación Orientada a Objetos. Para profundizar: Análisis y Diseño Orientado a Objetos.